# Should I mail my advisor concerning his attitude towards me, and possible re-use of my ideas by a colleague?

Tags: advisor, masters, plagiarism

I have been doing some research for my masterthesis. I had a supervisor for this task, who was (to my opinion) quite harsh and unhelpful in his feedback. I pursued it nevertheless, and continued on the work that I had been doing; but got somewhat annoyed.

Some time ago, he sent me a (edit: yet unpublished) paper by one of his colleagues (with whom he had previously been working with) on a topic that somewhat overlaps with the topic I had been working in. 3 out of the 5 concepts that I used in my paper are also presented in this paper (with a somewhat different name, but the construct on its' own is the same); although the actual question, and other concepts were also added to it - so it's not quite a copy-paste, but I had a sense that this (not yet published paper) was in some ways inspired by my work. The most troubling aspect I found was how my supervisor treated my ideas as 'unoriginal' and also did not give me much support throughout my work while he then send me something that I felt was actually originally coming from me.

I have contacted already a third person about this (edit: an ombuds-person, who is also a professor at my faculty), and am thinking about sending to my supervisor regarding my disappointments and questions about this issue later on, once I finished my exams and obtained my master.
But I don't expect much helpful answers back (I am slightly resentful of that moment, and I am wondering how I can do this at the same time politely and honestly).

I was wondering whether anyone had some similar experience, and could help me figure out what I should do? Should I let it go, later on? Do I also have any say in this?

It is not only my own personal situation that worries me, it's also about all future students who might have him as a supervisor who might go through something like this - which is everything but a nice way to finish a degree.

So if anyone has any experience, I'd love to hear about it.

**Update**
I send an email to my promotor, in which I somewhat mentioned my problems. He replied to me back that he was sorry that he was not more present to help me, that I should tell something to my advisor and that he will be there to support me if there is any conflict; that definitely something needs to be fixed here and that he is willing to repair the wrongs. So to anyone feeling stuck in a similar situation, I guess my best advice would be: talk about it, and with as many persons as you can - you might not have the answer directly from one person at one moment, but it also just helps figuring what the problem is in the first place. Thanks for everyone having replied in the comments, that was really nice & helpful! :)

Comment: Do you have any concrete evidence that the colleague of your supervisor actually used or even knew about your work? Is the third person you consulted a more experienced academic? While I am not doubting that some foul play might have took place, your description fits the "oh, someone already did it" scenario that happens so very often to everyone. So it would make a difference whether the third person advising confrontation is a student moved by your bad luck, or a member of a faculty that senses something's off.

Comment: Thanks for replying @lemon314. The third person I contacted is a professor at my University; and I did send him both my work and the yet unpublished paper so that he could have a look at it as an innocent eye. I don't have of course direct evidence, and I think the person that will soon publish it could easily defend that it had nothing to do with it. But I just scrolled through his academic profile, and found nothing that uses those concepts that I placed in my paper in his previous research; and also found out that he had been collaborating with my advisor recently.

Comment: Also, is the paper of the supervisor's colleague a preprint, a published article, a conference paper? And when did it appear? It would also help to indicate the field, firstly because if this is, say, mathematics, and that paper appeared in the journal, it conceivably was submitted a year ago or more, possibly before you even started your research (this is very field-dependent). Secondly, while this is only tangent to the question, there's the issue if prior publication harms your prospects of obtaining the degree (which I'm **NOT** expecting, but it is field-dependent again).

Comment: It is not yet published - it is submitted, and I think peer-reviewed (not sure about this though, but he send me just a draft of the paper, for reasons I really do not know, I was really surprised by this). So I think that this happened after I had written my first paper (my thesis is split into two parts: last year, I needed to plan out the research and this year I carried it out and need to write a final paper about it). And the field I am in is experimental psychology, I do not think that prior publication will have an impact on my degree.

Comment: And also: the draft that was send is somewhat related, but it is really not exactly on the research topic I was working on. It was more of the person doing the sort of research he was previously already carrying out, and adding some ingredients that looked to me suspiciously similar to some ingredients that I used.

Comment: and was there any message from your supervisor with that paper of their colleague, any reason they send it your way? I've been in the similar-ish situation, but the email from my supervisor started with "I'll contact them right away and make sure they cite your work properly!!!". Consider that your supervisor maliciously sending your work to their colleague for them to steal it, and then not only not concealing the fact from you but making you aware of the paper prior to its publication - that would be quite a bold move.

Comment: Like @lemon314, I'm wondering why your supervisor sent you the paper. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have no idea myself why he would send it to me. He told me "Be careful; this is an unpublished manuscript so don't share it. Look at the logical structure of it - maybe it can inspire you for your own paper!" Like I would be using the things from that paper in my own paper. I was quite shocked. I didn't do it, of course. And he didn't mention anything about mentioning me.

Comment: Oh and he said in the comments of a draft of my second paper: "Oh well, what you found (this and that) we actually already knew about it."

Comment: But why he send me this draft is a mystery to me as well. I have been thinking of asking him if he noticed the resemblances, if there was a reason why it seemed to me that the colleague had been 'recycling' my ideas; but he also will give FB on me later on, and I am afraid that this will affect my final grade.

Comment: @Kat I understand your feelings of disappointment and resent, but there really isn't anything you can do about this, since you cannot prove that your ideas were taken. Complete your masters instead; if you annoy your advisor too much he might not give you the masters, so better be safe than sorry. One thing to note: if this repeats again and again, you should find another advisor; if this occurs again and again you will need to draw a line between what the advisor should and should not do.

Comment: Thanks @user758469; I think this was the conclusion that I ended making for myself. Thankfully, I only have 2 months left and then I'll be leaving this institution. It just saddens me for my University, and for all prospective students. I was thinking of eventually keeping all the mails that I have, in case another student has somewhat of a similar experience with the same supervisor. Does that sound like a good idea?

Comment: @Kat, Yes (perhaps in a separate 'My Folder" which you can name with anything positive or negative )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have contacted already a third person about this (edit: an ombuds-person, who is also a professor at my faculty)

This ombudsperson is probably the person best suited to give advice about whether misconduct occurred and what your options may be. Given that you are already talking to an ombudsperson, I would not want to add my own speculation into the mix.

> [I] am thinking about sending to my supervisor regarding my disappointments and questions about this issue later on, once I finished my exams and obtained my master.

Your instinct to wait until after finalizing your degree is probably a good one. As for the advisability of writing such a letter at all: well, I am afraid I do not see much point. Certainly it seems unlikely that your advisor will say "Egads! I have seen the error of my ways and am overcome with remorse!" Your desire to protect future students is admirable, but unless the ombudsperson recommends further action, I suspect your options will be somewhat limited.

Comment: Thanks @cag51! (loved the quote: "Egads! I have seen the error of my ways and am overcome with remores!" - I think this is exactly why I dread sending him an email, because it obviously seems like he didn't see the problem). I ended up emailing as well with my promotor, who was supposed to mentor me but did not. He wrote me a mail back, apologising. I now think that my advisor just didn't realize that this paper was somewhat related to mine; or that he has a different opinion on what 'plagiarising' means. I will wait until after my degree is completed, just too much to handle for me otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for us to know which (if any) of the following two things is true:

1. your supervisor stole your ideas, wrote a paper about them with one of their colleagues, and is now feeding it back to you;
2. your supervisor and a colleague of theirs had been submitting a paper of theirs two years ago, it has been going through a tortuous and so far unsuccessful peer review process, and in the meantime your supervisor asked you to work on variants of parts of those ideas for your Master thesis.

If you cannot conclusively rule out option 2, do not assume that option 1 is actually the case.

---

As extra anecdotal evidence: a PhD student of mine approached me two months ago with the idea to collaborate on idea X. However, in 2019, another PhD student of mine had started working on a variation of that idea, let's call it X'. The paper on X' has just been accepted and appeared online in a journal publication three days ago. I haven't yet talked to the student with idea X about the paper on idea X', because I think that X and X' are different enough to merit separate publications, and the paper on X' had not yet been published. But if the student with idea X now finds the published paper and reads the abstract, and if they reason like you do, they will think that I stole their idea on X.

You might be in the same situation here. You might not. It's impossible for us to know.

Comment: Thanks @wetenschaap for your reply. You are right that my description is somewhat vague. The subject I have been working on was unrelated to any project my advisor had been working on (long story short: due to corona I needed to come up with something new, and I came up with that idea which he thought was good). And the paper he send me was very recent; he only send me a draft - so it is submitted, but I think only recently so. But it is exactly as you said: I had been working with X, and that colleague worked out X'; I didn't know about this, which was frustrating.

Comment: Especially because he didn't give me much support, while he knew of this other project on which I myself could find some help to work out and build up on my own project. But it appears to me that he didn't see the problem; I am not sure it was with any bad intention. He is a very young PhD student, and might not be aware of certain implicit rules/ethics concerning this (this is of course my own interpretation, it is hard for me to get to the ground truth)

Comment: Can I also ask: did X' follow from X, or did they just appear in parallel? And what if X' came because of X? Should the person offer to be a co-author, or at least be up to date about this related project? I am myself still a student, so I do not know what should and should not be done. I personally had a hard time seeing X' being worked out, while I was still working on X and received so little support on it.

Comment: X' and X appeared in parallel. But notice that you have the timeline wrong: we had already been working on X' for two years when the other student approached me with the idea for X. The paper on X' only made it through the review process just now.

I haven't connected these students, because I feel that X and X' are sufficiently different to warrant independent publications. But if they would read each others' works _superficially_, they may draw the conclusion that you have drawn. Both X and X' are a deviation from what I typically work on, so the situation you describe is not unusual.

Comment: I understand; That makes a lot of sense. You are right: it might be possible that I have misinterpreted the situation - and as I have mentioned previously: I have no strong evidence that it was happening otherwise. But I personally would have liked to know somewhat of the work of this colleague, because it could have helped me then to strengthen my own project.

Comment: I completely understand your feelings on the matter; they make complete sense for your personal situation. Simultaneously, your supervisor may find themselves in an awkward position. In the past, they may have let a student with idea X know that they've been working on X' already, and this student might have been discouraged by the perceived similarity of X and X'. If past experiences taught the supervisor that this impedes progress on X, they might not want to let students know of parallel works, even though you personally would have been able to handle it better than the student in the past.